# Need to export dataset from Collibra

Tags: api, collibra

I have collibra data governance set up in my company and I am trying to download dataset from it using API. I am not able find any tutorial/link which can explain how to use API to download files collibra using script. Any where I see it shows how to import into collibra and not export.

Any guidance/link will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In REST Core APIs, **Output Module** can be used to export as JSON, CSV, Excel and XML. Kindly refer this, https://developer.collibra.com/rest/rest-core-api/

And also follow **Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Output Module** documentation for more info on how to create TableViewConfig/ViewConfig. https://developer.collibra.com/rest/output-module/